# Why my back button does nothing?

Tags: java, android

I have a `AppCompatActivity` activity named `MainActivity` with the following code placed on `onCreate` method to show/hide back and menu button

```
getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
    new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onBackStackChanged() {
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(
             getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(
             getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0);
    }
});
```

This is my only activity, I use fragments for the different views. The back button shows perfectly when appropiated but does nothing when I click on it.

Do I have to put some code on fragments? I have checked many other similar questions but I'm not able to detect  what's missed

**EDIT**

Many solutions ask to override `onOptionsItemSelected` on Fragment or Activity but this method is not called when I click on the back button on toolbar.

**EDIT 2**

If I comment line

```
toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0);
```

then back button click opens navigation menu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switching between Android Navigation Drawer image and Up caret when using fragments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258020/switching-between-android-navigation-drawer-image-and-up-caret-when-using-fragme)

Comment: Do you write the code onBackPRessed() in MainActivity.

Comment: Full solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34026438/4409409

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to manually handle the home button as shown here : 
[catch toolbar home button click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582075/cannot-catch-toolbar-home-button-click-event)

then load the previous fragment from backstack: 
[Get Fragment from backstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702216/get-the-latest-fragment-in-backstack)

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work. `onBackPressed` is not called when I click back icon on the toolbar

Comment: I'm afraid I'm stuck with `onOptionsItemSelected` not being called on activity